# Filter duplicated messages Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to configure a Discord Bot made in Discord.js to filter URLs with the following schema "https://site.url/NUMBERS-LETTERS" so that the bot checks if "https://site.url/NUMBERS" has already been inputed by another user, and in that case, doesn't post the message.

```
    execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord){
        const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'link');
        if(!channel) return message.channel.send('link channel does not exist!');

        let messageArgs = args.join(' ');
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('FADF2E')
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setDescription(messageArgs);

        // Get messages
            channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 50 })
            .then(messages => console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`))
            
            
            channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 50 }).then(messages => {
                
                    channel.send(embed).then((msg) =>{
                        msg.react('');
                        msg.react('');
                        message.delete();
                    }).catch((err)=>{
                        throw err;
                    });
              })
        
    }
```

Would be really glad is someone might help me!

Comment: Note that `java` and `javascript` are two different programming languages. Thank you.

Comment: @Jakye sorry! must have missclicked the suggestion when I was choosing tags.

Answer (score 0):

First you should extract out the "NUMBERS" part out from the site url. You can use [the code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression/41445988#41445988). Or:

```
let reg = /https:\/\/site\.url\/(\d*)-/gmi;
let matches = (message.content.match(reg) || []).map(e => e.replace(reg, '$1'));
if(matches.length === 0) return; // no match
```

Then you'll need to keep track of it somewhere persistently. Recommend making an object outside of the function. Make the matched number the key to this object.

```
// outside
let numberTracker = {};

// inside
if(numberTracker[matches[i]] === undefined) { // no body has linked this number before
  numberTracker[matches[i]] = message; // store this message

} else { // uh oh another user already linked this url before

}
```

Not sure what else you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. What I am tryting to do is a twitter URL checker. 
My and my friends share twitter links like https://twitter.com/user/status/1367883378645667851-RLF but we don't want to send the same tweet twice. Is the link is not douple, then prints in #links. This is my entire code RN https://pastebin.com/cDKaFArz

Comment: Would also like to loop in case someone sends more links per line at the same time, but didn't managed to.